# Qt - How to show gif(animated) image in QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, animation, gif

I am trying to use one blinking image in QGraphicsPixmapItem. The image has shown without the animation effect. The below is the original image, the following is the QGraphicsScene which uses this image in QGraphicsPixmapItem. Can anybody say how to achieve this?.

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [GIF animation in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248243/gif-animation-in-qt)

Comment: @Mat Thank you for your suggestion. But that answer can't serve my purpose. Because there is no way to add QMovie to QGraphicsPixMapItem.

Comment: Indeed, but you can make a QGraphicsProxyWidget from a QLabel and put that in your scene instead of the QGraphicsPixmapItem. This is also listed in the answers to the question linked above.

Comment: @Mat thank you.  That worked very well except the background is not transparent.

Answer (score 5):

Check this answer from [Nosf](https://forum.qt.io/user/nosf) on this [thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/15658/solved-how-to-play-gif-animation-in-qgraphicsview-widget):

> I guess you could add a `QGraphicsProxyWidget` to your scene
>
> set a `QLabel` to the `ProxyWidget` and then set the label to use your gif as a `QMovie`.

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
QLabel *gif_anim = new QLabel();
QMovie *movie = new QMovie(image);

gif_anim->setMovie(movie);
movie->start();

QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = scene.addWidget(gif_anim);
```